# run functions with differents parameters with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, parameter-passing, argparse

I have functions that i want to run with differents parameters

Here is the directory structure:

```
App/  
   ├─ main.py
   └─ fcts1.py
   └─ fcts2.py
   └─ File1.csv
   └─ File2.csv
   └─ Files/  
      └─B.xlsx
      └─A.txt
      └─C.xlsx
```

**Exp 1:**

```
file1 = "file1.csv"
from fcts1 import fct1

    def A_fct(fileA):
        df = pd.read_csv(file1)
        dfA = pd.read_csv(fileA,skiprows=2,sep=r"\s*\|\s*")
        fct1()
    def B_fct(fileB):
        df = pd.read_csv(file1)
        dfB = pd.read_excel(fileB)
        fct1()
    def C_fct(fileC):
        df = pd.read_csv(file1)
        dfC = pd.read_excel(fileC)
        fct1()
```

**Exp 2 :**

```
file2 = "file2.csv"
from fcts2 import fct1

    def A_fct(fileA):
        df = pd.read_csv(file2)
        dfA = pd.read_csv(fileA,skiprows=2,sep=r"\s*\|\s*")
        fct1()
    def B_fct(fileB):
        df = pd.read_csv(file2)
        dfB = pd.read_excel(fileB)
        fct1()
    def C_fct(fileC):
        df = pd.read_csv(file2)
        dfC = pd.read_excel(fileC)
        fct1()
```

**NB1:** fct1() in fcts1.py is not the same as fct1() in fcts2.py

**NB2** : every function performs a specific task

I already defined a dict with the relationship file_name => function because I want to read file name(A/B/C..) and call the convenable function for each file in Files folder

```
name_to_func = {
    "A": A_fct,
    "B": B_fct,
    ...
}
```

then to iterate over files in a folder, and call the function with

```
import os

path = '/your/path/here'

name_to_func = {
    "A": A_fct,
    "B": B_fct
}

for file_name in os.listdir(path):
    file_prefix = file_name.split('.')[0]
    name_to_func[file_prefix](file_name)
```

Sometimes i want to run those functions with `df = pd.read_excel(file1)` and `fct1()` from the file fcts1.py and sometimes with
`df = pd.read_excel(file2)` and `fct1()` from the file fcts2.py
How can i do it please?

Answer (score 0):

Try using alias for your functions

```
from fcts1 import fct1 as f1
from fcts2 import fct1 as f2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace these 6 functions with one:

```
def fct(file_number, file_letter, function):
    # Key idea: you can pass functions as arguments
    df = pd.read_excel(file_number)
    dfA = pd.read_excel(file_letter)
    function()
```

This can be called like this:

```
import fcts1, fcts2

fct("file1.csv", whatever_file, fcts1.fct1)
fct("file2.csv", whatever_file, fcts2.fct1)
```

Comment: no, i can't every function performs a specific task

Comment: Is the code you posted not representative of the code you're actually running, then? As far as I understand, the functions in the code you posted perform the exact same task.

Comment: Yes it's not the code that i actually running it just an exp

Comment: As long as code in your question isn't representative of the code you're running, you'll likely be getting irrelevant answers. It's important that the examples contain all most important properties of your actual code. You say the actual functions perform different tasks, but the functions in your questions do the same thing. The answers will likely address this, since it's an obvious simplification, but apparently this won't help you since your code is actually different. See: [mcve]. (IMO, it's not sufficient to say "every function performs a specific task" since it's not true for this code)

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a settings/parameter dictionary at the top of `main.py`, and then passing it to your main function. Essentially this means that you only need to modify this dictionary, not the code itself, in order to re-run your analysis with different files or functions.

Example:

```
from fcts1 import fct1 as function1
from fcts2 import fct1 as function2

SETTINGS = {
    'file1': "file1.csv",
    'file2': "file2.csv",
    'function': function1,
}

def main(file1, file2, function):
    df1 = pd.read_excel(file1)
    df2 = pd.read_excel(file2)
    function()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(**SETTINGS)
```

Two things to note:

- I've aliased the `fct1`s to `function1` and `function2` in order to be able to differentiate them. In reality, your code would benefit a lot from better variable names.
- We're using a starred expression in `main(**SETTINGS)`, which means that the arguments in the `SETTINGS` dictionary are properly delivered to the `main` function as long as the dictionary's key names match the function's parameter names.

Comment: Thanks but actually i want to use either file1 or file 2 not both at the same time

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve. If you just need either `file1` or `file2`, you only need a single "file" key in the dictionary.

Comment: Yes but how can i pass the arguments in the SETTINGS dictionary in all my functions automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

to my understanding

you has 3 function to read file1 for fileA,B,C, then call fct1() in fcts1

another 3 functions to read file2 for fileA,B,C, then call fct1() in fcts2

you want to switch between these 2 cases, right?

add another layer to the name_to_func for these 2 cases may solve your question

```
import os

from fcts1 import fct1 as f1
from fcts2 import fct1 as f2

file1 = "file1.csv"
file2 = "file2.csv"

def f1_A_fct(fileA):
    df = pd.read_csv(file1)
    dfA = pd.read_csv(fileA,skiprows=2,sep=r"\s*\|\s*")
    f1()
def f1_B_fct(fileB):
    df = pd.read_csv(file1)
    dfB = pd.read_excel(fileB)
    f1()
def f1_C_fct(fileC):
    df = pd.read_csv(file1)
    dfC = pd.read_excel(fileC)
    f1()

def f2_A_fct(fileA):
    df = pd.read_csv(file2)
    dfA = pd.read_csv(fileA,skiprows=2,sep=r"\s*\|\s*")
    f2()
def f2_B_fct(fileB):
    df = pd.read_csv(file2)
    dfB = pd.read_excel(fileB)
    f2()
def f2_C_fct(fileC):
    df = pd.read_csv(file2)
    dfC = pd.read_excel(fileC)
    f2()


name_to_func = {
    "A": {"f1": f1_A_fct, "f2": f2_A_fct},
    "B": {"f1": f1_B_fct, "f2": f2_B_fct},
    "C": {"f1": f1_C_fct, "f2": f2_C_fct}
}

def get_func(a_b_c, f1_f2):
    return name_to_func[a_b_c][f1_f2]


# set to 'f1' if you want to run with df = pd.read_excel(file1) and fct1() from the file fcts1.py
# set to 'f2' if you want to run with df = pd.read_excel(file2) and fct1() from the file fcts2.py
f1_or_f2 = 'f1' 
path = '/your/path/here'
for file_name in os.listdir(path):
    file_prefix = file_name.split('.')[0]
    get_func(file_prefix, f1_or_f2)(file_name)
```

Updated:

if you only want the value of name_to_func contain a function instead of another dictionary

add an if-else checking will do the trick

```
# set to 'f1' if you want to run with df = pd.read_excel(file1) and fct1() from the file fcts1.py
# set to 'f2' if you want to run with df = pd.read_excel(file2) and fct1() from the file fcts2.py
f1_or_f2 = 'f1'

name_to_func = {
    "A": f1_A_fct if f1_or_f2 == 'f1' else f2_A_fct,
    "B": f1_B_fct if f1_or_f2 == 'f1' else f2_B_fct,
    "C": f1_C_fct if f1_or_f2 == 'f1' else f2_C_fct
}



path = '/your/path/here'
for file_name in os.listdir(path):
    file_prefix = file_name.split('.')[0]
    name_to_func[file_prefix](file_name)
```

Comment: thanks for answering me, yes you understand me verry well, except that i want only to keep one function to A and just select with which functions(f1 or f2) to run it.

Comment: only to keep one function to A , does this means you want the value of the `name_to_func ` is a function instead of a dictionary? If yes, you can change the `{"f1": f1_A_fct, "f2": f2_A_fct}` to `f1_A_fct if f1_or_f2 == 'f1' else f2_A_fct` and move the line `f1_or_f2 = 'f1' ` above this. then you can run this as your code does `name_to_func[file_prefix](file_name)`

Comment: Yes this is what i mean, i will try your solution